# Trying to transform position of gameobject unity using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

I need some help in trying to change the position of an gameobject and its speed.  I know to translate the gameObject but I don't know how to increase the speed of how it translates.  I'm using the unity game engine by the way.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class lightning : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This is lightning
    private GameObject name;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       name=GameObject.Find("car");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
     if (Input.Keydone("r")
       door.transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Scene lights are a completely separate thing from the device's screen brightness.

Comment: which is to say, do you really mean screen brightness or do you mean lights in the scene? - your code and description are contrary

Comment: I would suggest using the post processing stack to achieve something like this. A mixture of Bloom and Auto Exposure should do the trick. You can't turn up the devices brightness.

Comment: @BrandonMiller In 2019.2 beta, there is a writeable [`Screen.brightness`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-brightness.html) field for iOS and android devices:

Comment: I'm using a game engine.  I'm trying to alter the brightness of the game engine.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround you can use is a black filter(preferably Image) on UI layer that covers the whole screen. You can change filter's opacity accordingly to achieve the feeling of 'dimmed' screen.

Comment: Please also provide some sample code in your answer to show how it should be done to improve your answer quality and clearness.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having trouble with speed and acceleration.
I added a velocity variable and an acceleration variable with the two you can make objects go faster and faster with time.

Since this is Physics I'd recommend you to use a rigidbody on your gameobject
and manipulate its speed or to apply a force (force = mass * acceleration)
so by adding a force it will give the object an acceleration.

```
//This is lightning
private GameObject name;
private float speedFactor = 20;
private float accelearationFactor = 5;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   name=GameObject.Find("car");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
 if (Input.Keydone("r") {
   door.transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * speedFactor * Time.deltaTime);
   speedFactor += accelearationFactor * Time.deltaTime;
 }
}
```